# How do I dynamically update the reference data in J2EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee

My application is hosted on weblogic 10.3. We are using Jee 6. 
In our application we have lot of reference data which needs to be updated once in a while without restarting the server. This reference data is used in other part of the application as drop down option and those dropdown option should show the latest update. Most of the reference data table structure is very similar.
I would like to know what is the best way to achive the requirements with least amount of code. 
If Jee has any built in feature for this kind requirements(I belive this is std requirement in most of the web applications)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for caching with something like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).  With ehcache, setup is extremely easy and there is minimal coding required.  Depending on your needs you can configure each cache independently to refresh automatically after a certain amount of time, or immediately based on some trigger.  You should notice immediate performance improvements if you are going to the database frequently for your reference data, and will avoid all unnecessary server restarts just to refresh data.

An extra benefit of using this type of caching approach, is that a caching API will eventually be part of the standard JEE specification so your code will be JEE compliant with minimal code changes.